# How to specify the location of an item in an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's say I have an object user like this.

```
  const user =  {
    nationality: 'Italian',
    age: 24,
    name: {
      firstName: 'rocky',
      lastName: 'balboa',
    },
  };
```

I updated the `firstName` item in the `name`. I wanna convey this change to some function so it can also update the firstName in it's own user object with same structure too. What's the best way to do that ?

As per my understandings, to specify firstName, we would use `user[name][firstName]`. But how do I send this to another object, let's say `primeUsers` so it can update itself too ?

```
  const primeUser =  {
    nationality: 'Italian',
    age: 24,
    name: {
      firstName: 'rocky',
      lastName: 'balboa',
    },
  };
```

One way would be to send an array of the "levels". So i'll send an array

```
const levels = ["name", "firstName"];
```

But i'm not sure how i'll use this to update the `firstName` in `primeUser` ? I'm sorry it seems weird and i'm not explaining it very clearly. Hope you understand what i'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: `const` keyword does not allow you to modify the object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const. You should use `let` or `var`

Comment: Does user and primeUser have same structure ?

Comment: @cl3m `const` allows you to update the object keys.

Comment: @SaurabhPandey Yes. Exact same structure.

Comment: @ateev: ahah, thanks for the info! Can't you use `Object.assign()` then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @cl3m I don't wanna copy the whole object, Just update it.

Comment: @AteevChopra In case the second object is a reference, you don't have to do anything, but from what I understand, you seem to have 2 references on the same data

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript **getter**/**setter** functions:

> The **get** syntax binds an object property to a function that will be
>   called when that property is looked up.

---

> The **set** syntax binds an object property to a function to be called
>   when there is an attempt to set that property.

```js
const primeUser =  {
    nationality: 'Italian',
    age: 24,
    name: {
        get firstName() {
            return this._firstName;
        },
        set firstName(fName) {
            this._firstName = fName;
        },
        lastName: 'balboa',
    },
};
const user =  {
    nationality: 'Italian',
    age: 24,
    name: {
        get firstName() {
            return this._firstName;
        },
        set firstName(fName) {
            this._firstName = fName;
            primeUser.name.firstName = fName;
        },
        lastName: 'balboa',
    },
};

user.name.firstName = 'rocky';

console.log(primeUser.name.firstName);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: Though i understand you are just replying to the post, I find it interesting to not mention that he could simply use a reference. From the data I see, there is no need to maintain 2 structures, in case the exact same data would be coming from the same source

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna convey this change to some function so it can also update the
>   firstName in it's own user object with same structure too

You can define a setter on the `firstName` property and pass the setter function as your own which will be invoked everytime this property changes

**Demo**

```js
const user =  {
    nationality: 'Italian',
    age: 24,
    name: {
      firstName: 'rocky',
      lastName: 'balboa',
    },
  };
  
function yourFunction(val) {console.log("value set ",val)}
  
Object.defineProperty(user.name, "firstName" ,{set: yourFunction});

user.name.firstName = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all properties and update the different values.

It works for any same structure of source and target object. If a found property is an iterable object, then a recursive function call is made with the actual property of source and target object.

```js
function update(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        if (source[k] && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
            update(source[k], target[k]);
            return;
        }
        if (target[k] !== source[k]) {
            target[k] = source[k];
        }
    });
}

const user = { nationality: 'Italian', age: 24, name: { firstName: 'rocky', lastName: 'foo' } };
const primeUser = { nationality: 'Italian', age: 24, name: { firstName: 'rocky', lastName: 'balboa' } };

update(user, primeUser);
console.log(primeUser);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With generator of empty objects as well.

```js
function update(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        if (source[k] && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
            update(source[k], target[k] = target[k] || {});
            return;
        }
        if (target[k] !== source[k]) {
            target[k] = source[k];
        }
    });
}

const user = { nationality: 'Italian', age: 24, name: { firstName: 'rocky', lastName: 'balboa' } };
const primeUser = { };

update(user, primeUser);
console.log(primeUser);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```